# ORM and prefixes for the tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

Task this, when registering the customer in the database we need to create a set of tables with a unique prefix, it is generally possible to implement using EF?

Comment: I really think that the best way to manage this is to use a schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it should work, or at least be a good start point. First you need to tell your context the prefix you will be using, I'd do this in the constructor. Then in the `OnModelCreating` override, use the prefix for the table names:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _prefix;

    public MyContext(string prefix)
    {
        _prefix = prefix;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Types()
            .Configure(entity => entity.ToTable(_prefix + entity.ClrType.Name));
    }

}
```